# SSRS indicator based on a date value

Tags: reporting-services

I have a simple table in a SSRS report.  I am using SQL Server 2008R2.  I have an indicator on one of the fields.  I need to know if the date in the field is there or not.  If the user has put a date in the field, I need a green indicator, if not I need the indicator to be red.  Basically an on or off functionality.  I have tried to use `=IsDate(Fields!ImportDate.Value)` as the fx for the indicator but no luck.  Anyone have a good tutorial on indicators that includes date related fields?

Comment: Have you tried `=IsNothing(Fields!ImportDate.Value)`? This may work if the field is null from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use `IsNothing` to verified if a date is valid or not, before formatting it; i.e.:

```
=IIf(Not IsNothing(Fields!YourDate.Value), FormatDateTime(Fields!YourDate.Value), "")
```

In your case you can use `IsNothing` like this:

```
=IIf(Not IsNothing(Fields!ImportDate.Value), "Green!", "Red!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!DateField.Value),"Red","Green")
```